# How to scroll with Appium 1.7.1 using TouchAction

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios

I'm having trouble with scrolling down to a certain element in an iOS and Android app. Since the update from Appium 1.6.3 to 1.7.1 and io.appium to 6.1.0 the swipe method is deprecated and the only solution for it is to use TouchActions.

I tried to solve it with TouchActions but it didn't scroll at all or the scroll direction was wrong.

My solution so far looks like this, maybe someone can explain what I'm doing wrong:

```
public void scrollDownUntilElementVisible(WebElement element){
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(getDriver());
    for(int i=0; i<dimensions.getHeight();i++){
       if(element.isDisplayed()){
          break;
       }else{
          touchAction.press(0,0).moveTo(element).release().perform();
       }
    }
}
```

It's not the complete code, but I hope you get the idea.

How would it work if I would use the x,y-coordinates instead of the webElement I look for in my example? It does not work like the swipe method from the version before, or I didn't do it right. Maybe someone can explain it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I needed scroll to find elements which are out of the screen. What I come up with is:

1. Search for the element you need on the current/visible screen.
2. If the element is not found (i.e. out of the screen) - `scrollDown` (in my case I was needed only scroll down) and go to step 1 again. I had limited the test with 4 iterations as it was enough in my case, so use your own condition here.

```java
private void scrollDown() {
    //if pressX was zero it didn't work for me
    int pressX = driver.manage().window().getSize().width / 2;
    // 4/5 of the screen as the bottom finger-press point
    int bottomY = driver.manage().window().getSize().height * 4/5;
    // just non zero point, as it didn't scroll to zero normally
    int topY = driver.manage().window().getSize().height / 8;
    //scroll with TouchAction by itself
    scroll(pressX, bottomY, pressX, topY);
}

/*
 * don't forget that it's "natural scroll" where 
 * fromY is the point where you press the and toY where you release it
 */
private void scroll(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
    touchAction.longPress(fromX, fromY).moveTo(toX, toY).release().perform();
}
```

P.S. you could get coordinates from the element and use it in `scroll`.

P.S.S. I used appium 1.6.5

Comment: Thank you @Yaroslav Havrylovych. The above code is working from top to bottom. Can you please help me from bottom to top how to scroll?

Comment: I haven't seen your comment before. Did you try just to change scroll to: scroll(pressX, topY, pressX, bottomY); ? Or you need something else (maybe I didn't get the question)? It's night at my place, so I can check only next day.

Comment: Actually, it's working as expected from top to bottom scrolling. But I need to scroll from bottom to top.

Comment: The answer from @YaroslavHavrylovych is working, but if you update your appium version you will see that the x,y coordinates are no longer available for the TouchActions. You will have to use PointOption where you can encapsulate the x,y coordinate. Additionally a WaitOption should be added if you want to perform multiple scrolls to locate an element.

Answer (score 9):

On Latest Version of Appium need to add(**PointOption.point** while passing the coordinates) some code for scrolling using TouchAction:

```
private void scrollDown() {
    //if pressX was zero it didn't work for me
    int pressX = driver.manage().window().getSize().width / 2;
    // 4/5 of the screen as the bottom finger-press point
    int bottomY = driver.manage().window().getSize().height * 4/5;
    // just non zero point, as it didn't scroll to zero normally
    int topY = driver.manage().window().getSize().height / 8;
    //scroll with TouchAction by itself
    scroll(pressX, bottomY, pressX, topY);
}



private void scroll(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
    touchAction.longPress(PointOption.point(fromX, fromY)).moveTo(PointOption.point(toX, toY)).release().perform();
}
```

Comment: This perfectly works for normal scrolling and whereas in my case the screen is separated into two section. Section 1 is static and  Section 2 is scrollable. How do we handle here?