# How to scroll in iOS app using Selenium-Appium v1.7.2

Tags: appium-ios

I have used the below method but it shows error on `Swipe()` method. This method is not available in driver class. So, please suggest if any other way we can scroll in `iOS Appium v1.7.2`.

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int x = size.getWidth() / 2;
int starty = (int) (size.getHeight() * 0.60);
int endy = (int) (size.getHeight() * 0.10);
driver.swipe(x, starty, x, endy, 2000);
```

Comment: As driver.swipe is deprecated in appium java client.Take reference of http://appium.io/test/fixtures/sample.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scroll with Appium 1.7.1 using TouchAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282417/how-to-scroll-with-appium-1-7-1-using-touchaction)

Answer (score 1):

For latest versions of appium you cannot use `.swipe()` because this method is deprecated.You have to achieve the scroll functionality in latest appium using `TouchAction` class.

Please refer the below link on Touch Actions :

[Touch Actions in Appium](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method,

```
/**
     * Swipe vertically upwards
     *
     * @author xxx
     * 
     * @param ele
     *            -reference field/area to swipe
     * 
     */
public void verticalSwipe_Up(MobileElement ele) {
    Dimension size = ele.getSize();
    ElementOption press = element(ele, size.width / 2, (int) (size.height * .80));
    ElementOption move = element(ele, size.width / 2, 25);
    TouchAction swipe = new TouchAction(getDriver()).press(press).waitAction(waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000))).moveTo(move).release();
    // ofSeconds(2)
    swipe.perform();
}
```

You can change the values accordingly to perform swipe down/right/left